# CodeIgniter and submit callbacks

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to check (before submit to db) whenever there is a game in database which has title and platform the same as the one submitted.

I have this controller:

```
    public function addGame($id = null) { // ID is for children games
    $this->load->library(array('images','form_validation'));
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->model('contrib_model');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('gameTitle', 'Tytuł gry', 'required|callback_checkGamePlatform');

    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        $data['title'] = 'Dodaj grę';
        $data['genres'] = $this->contrib_model->getGenres();
        $data['platforms'] = $this->contrib_model->getPlatforms();
        $data['developers'] = $this->contrib_model->getDevelopers();

        $this->template->load('template','theme/contribute/addGame',$data);
    } else {
        $data['submit'] = $this->contrib_model->insertGame();; //submits data
        $this->load->view('theme/contribute/emptyPage', $data); //loads view
    }
}

public function checkGamePlatform() {
    $platform = $this->input->post('gamePlatform');
    $game = $this->input->post('gameTitle');

    $q = $this->contrib_model->checkGame($game,$platform);
    echo $q;
    if($q === '0') {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('checkGamePlatform','gra istnieje');
    }
}
```

And this model:

```
    function checkGame($name,$platform) {
    $q = $this->db->get_where('games',array(
        'name' => $name,
        'plat' => $platform
    ));

    return $q -> num_rows();

}
```

The problem is, it doesn't work at all. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a game of the same type, you will want to return an error message. 
Furthermore, the callback must return boolean values.

In `checkGamePlatform`:

```
if ($q > 0) {
     $this->form_validation->set_message('checkGamePlatform','gra istnieje');
     return FALSE;
}
return TRUE;
```

Comment: Works great! Can you also tell me, can I, instead of showing message, load a view? I tried with regular `$this->load->view('error.php');` instead of `set_message` thing, but it didn't worked.

Comment: Glad it helped. I don't know if its possible to load a view, however its seems unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if($q === '0')
```

to

```
if($q === 0)
```

because `num_rows()` will return integer value while you are comparing against string.